# Are STL container elements explicitly required to be (noexcept) destructible?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

C++11 (and C++14) STL containers have `noexcept` destructors and `clear()` member functions.

This implies that the elements should have `noexcept` destructors too, or at least that the actual elements stored in containers should not throw any exceptions when destroyed—or more correctly, that the corresponding `allocator_traits<Allocator>::destroy` call should not throw.

Is this specified as a requirement (explicitly or implied by another explicit requirement) anywhere in the standard? If not, why?

I know `is_nothrow_constructible` requires a `noexcept` destructor, but `is_constructible` alone doesn’t, and container requirements are specified in terms of concepts rather than type traits templates anyway.

Comment: The container destructor could catch and ignore any exceptions from the element's destructor(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **17.6.4.8/1** In certain cases (replacement functions, handler functions, operations on types used to instantiate standard
>   library template components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C++ program.
>   If these components do not meet their requirements, the Standard places no requirements on the
>   implementation.
>
> **17.6.4.8/2** In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> ...
>
> - if any replacement function or handler function or destructor operation exits via an exception, unless specifically allowed in the
>     applicable *Required behavior:* paragraph.

Comment: Hm… I’ve just realized: there needs to be a similar requirement on user-supplied allocators, right? Does one exist?

Comment: In **17.6.3.5** table 28, an entry for `allocate` says "`allocate` may raise an appropriate exception."; the entry for `deallocate` says "Does not throw
exceptions." Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Ah, right! Yes, that’s exactly what I meant, thanks. For some reason it didn’t occur to me to look for that table in that section.